# Default Credit Card flag in mySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I store a reference to a credit card and a user_id in a cards table. I need to modify the design so a user can have multiple cards registered. In doing so, **I need to store which card is the default.**

A user can delete all their cards, and can choose which card is the default.

I was thinking about adding a flag to the cards table like so.

```
--Cards Table--

card_ref | user_id | default
------------------------------
  72138  |    12   |    0
  42356  |    12   |    1
```

When a user changes their default card, would I have to set all other default flags to 0 first? Should I just set all to 0 or select the default and set to 0.

When inserting a new card, would I have to check if there are existing cards, and if not, set the new one as default?

Comment: You can also store the default credit card in the user table.  Then you don't have to worry about updates on multiple rows when the default changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your specific questions are:

No, you would not have to perform an update on all cards associated with that user. Only the current default card and the new default card records would require updates. This of course assumes that your records have not become corrupt and have multiple default cards for one user due to previous failed updates or bugs in your code.

Possibly, your second question is ultimately a design consideration. Will you require there be a default card? If so then the answer is yes, you would need to query for existing cards and update the default accordingly.

Gordon Linoff offers a good alternative.

Another alternative would be to extend your schema by adding a new table that exists solely to hold default card information (user Id and card id being the fields) with user id as the primary key. The advantage to this alternative is that you will not implicitly expose new data (that perhaps you don't want existing data consumers to have access to)  to existing code or queries that pull whole records when performing a query.